# Normalization of tables into 1NF

Tags: sql, database, database-design, normalization

I'm struggling to breakdown the database into the 1st Normal Form.

Note: I have broken down the data requirements into a UNF flat-file table, i was going to put the image below but my reputation is not higher than 10 as of yet. However i will list my UNF representation

These are the Data requirements;

- Each office has a manager (who tends to also be a senior instructor), several senior instructors, instructors, and administrative staffs. The manager is responsible for the day-to-day running of the office.
- Clients must first register at an office, which includes completion of an application form, which records their personal details. Before the first lesson, a client is requested to attend an interview with an instructor to assess the needs of the client and to ensure that the client holds a valid provisional driving license. A client is free to ask for a particular instructor or to request that an instructor be changed at any stage throughout the process of learning to drive. After the interview, the first lesson is booked. A client may request individual lessons or book at a block of lessons for a reduced fee.
- An individual lesson is for one hour, which begins and ends at the office. A lesson is with a particular instructor in a particular car at a given time.  Lessons can start as early as 08:00am, and as late as 08:00pm. After each lesson, the instructor records the progress made by the client and notes the mileage used during the lesson.
- The school has a pool of cars, which are adapted for the purposes of teaching. Each instructor is allocated to a particular car. As well as teaching, the instructors are free to use the cars for personal use. The cars are inspected at regular intervals for faults.
- Once ready, a client applies for a driving test date. To obtain a full driving license, the client must pass both the driving and written parts of the test. It is the responsibility of the instructor to ensure that the client is best prepared for all aspects of the test. The instructor is not responsible for testing the client and is not in the car during the test, but should be available to drop off and pick up the client before and after the test at the testing centre. If the client fails the test, the instructor must record the reasons for the failure.

Normalisation representation of the UNF of driving school:

```
OFFICE(
OfficeID,OfficeName,OfficeAddress,OfficePostcode,ManagerID,ManagerNAME,
ManagerTelephone,

[StaffID,StaffRole,StaffName,StaffSurname,StaffAddress,StaffPostcode,StaffSex,StaffD.O.B,
InstructorID,InstructorName,InstructorSurname,InstructorTelephone, CarID,CarRegistration,CarFaults,FaultDescription,

[ClientID,ClientName,ClientSurname,ClientAddress,ClientPostcode,ClientTelephone,ClientSex, 
InterviewID,Interviewer,ValidProvisional LessonID,LessonTime,LessonType,LessonPrice,LessonMileage,LessonProgress,
TestID,TestType,TestResult,Attempts,Failure Reason,Date Achieved]
)
```

If you wish to see the UNF i'll e-mail you.

Comment: `I'm struggling to breakdown the database into the 1st Normal Form.`  What's giving you trouble?

Comment: The whole concept of repeating attributes i have StaffRole and StaffSex repeating in the StaffID for example. The Managers name occurs in both the staff and instructor entities.

Comment: Does that class as repeating data? since same names appear in ManagerName,StaffName,InstructorName and Interviwer.

Comment: @MalphasWats: [Homework doesn't matter.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You would need the following tables:

```
ROLES
role_id
role_name

EMPLOYEES
employee_id
forename
surname
role  (fk, -> roles.role_id)
telephone 
gender
address
postcode
dob
```

If you're going to have several telephone numbers for a person, then consider storing them in a different table; also be aware of problems with a single address field. You shouldn't need a separate table for instructors; these are simply employees whose role is that of instructor.

```
OFFICES
office_id
office_name
address
manager (fk, -> employees.employee_id)

CLIENTS
client_id
forename
surname
address
postcode
telephone
gender
has_driving_license
interviewdate
interviewer   (fk, -> employees.employee_id)
```

I don't think that you need a separate table of interviews as long as each client is interviewed only once

```
CARS
license
description

LESSONS
lesson_id
curdate
client   (fk, -> clients.client_id)
instructor  (fk, -> employees.employee_id)
car      (fk, -> cars.license)
price
invoice
receipt

RESULTS
result_id
description

TESTS
test_id
client   (fk, -> clients.client_id)
curdate
result   (fk, -> results.result_id)
```

There is no need for an 'attempts' field - you can count how many entries there are in the 'tests' table for each client in order to know how many times each client attempted the test.

I hope that this is enough to get you started with a database.

EDIT 19/12/12: I've added the foreign key relationships and a new table, RESULTS.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just needed to kickstart some where with these practice ones, so that i get concept of normalization when it comes to the real thing!

Comment: @Bryan: You've chosen something quite complicated to practice with! At least, complicated in terms of the number of tables required, but otherwise fairly simple.

Comment: Sorry to ask but why is Roles in it's own table?

Comment: I'm designing the ERD now is it possible to have any guidance on the relationships between tables?

Comment: @Bryan: Regarding roles, any text string which would appear as a value in several records should be moved to a separate table. This way, one restricts the number of values available. In other words, the 'role' field in the 'employees' table would be constrained to 'manager', 'instructor', 'admin' and 'senior instructor'. You wouldn't be able to enter misspelled values or new values such as 'junior instructor'.

Comment: sorry to interrupt but i don't get how manager would be a foreign key in the office table. "Each office has a manager (who tends to also be a senior instructor), several senior instructors, instructors, and administrative staffs. The manager is responsible for the day-to-day running of the office." wouldn't it be one office has many employees so office_id would be in employees as a foreign key. The only way i can see employee being in office_id is if employee is a one-to-one office as office only has one manager. but the office has multiple staff. please help clear this up :s for me. thanks